# Unable to delete a specific post from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mern

Thee app.get rout is to display the post content where I have a delete button from which I want to delete the specific post and render back to home route but unable to perform that task please help

```
     //This is the app.js code in which I think the error sustain in delete part

    app.get("/posts/:postId", function (req, res) {
      let requestedPostId = req.params.postId;
      Post.findOne({ _id: requestedPostId }, function (err, post) {
        res.render("post", {
          title: post.title,
          content: post.content,
        });
      });
    });
    app.delete("/posts/:postId", function (req, res) {
      Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.postId }, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          res.send("SuccesFully Deleted this Post");
        } else {
          res.send(err);
        }
      });
    });
// This the the ejs file containing the delete button

<form class="delete" action="/posts/:postId" method="delete">

        <button class="btn btn-danger delete-btn" type="submit">
            <a class="delete-btn-a" href="/">Delete this Blog</a></button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the post route under which I used the deleteOne property of MongoDB

```
app.post("/posts/:postId/delete", function (req, res) {
  Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.postId }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("SuccesFully Deleted this Post");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

The issue was in my ejs file in which I was not using the ejs syntax to get the post Id for operation

```
<form class="delete" action="/posts/<%=postId%>/delete" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete-btn" type="submit" title="Delete this blog">
            <a class="btn-a"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></a>
        </button>
    </form>
```

I Hope Whosever is reading this post will understand if any issue you can comment on and ask I will be pleased to solve the issue